# How to export table data to sap using sap function ocx VB.Net web application

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, abap

I'm about to Create an application using visual basic.net but I'm using SAP database (VB.NET SAP Function ocx) to call data. I can export individual parameter to sap but i don't know how to export data table..
Please help me guys. Thank You

Regards
miziel..

Answer (score 0):

One way I know of is creating a remote enabled function module. You can send in a table or extract a table that way.

Comment: I already created the module where in i will throw all my data from VB.net My problem is what syntax should i use to export table data. I can export individual parameter by the syntax codes.exports("COSTCENTER")= txtCostCenter.text. But i don't know how to export tables. Thank you so much